# How do I use autoload to correctly load custom configuration?

Tags: emacs, autoload

I use the following structure in my emacs config: For each programming mode I use, I maintain configuration in a file called programming-mode-config.el. (So python configuration will go into python-mode-config.el etc).

Earlier, I used to require each of these files in my init.el. The drawback of this approach was that my start-up time was huge. So this weekend, I sat down and converted all the requires into autoloads. Now my init file looks like this:

```
(autoload 'python-mode "python-mode-config" "Load python config" t)
```

Thus python config will not be loaded until I open a python file. This helped bring down my start-up time to about 1 second, but it doesn't work properly in all cases. For example,

```
(autoload 'erc "erc-mode-config" "Load configuration for ERC" t)
```

does not load my erc tweaks at all. Looking at the autoload documentation, it states that:

```
Define FUNCTION to autoload from FILE.
...
If FUNCTION is already defined other than as an autoload,
this does nothing and returns nil.
```

So I'm guessing that the erc config is not loaded because ERC comes 'in-built' with emacs whereas python-mode is a plugin I use. Is there any way I can get my erc configuration to load only when I actually use erc? The only other alternative I see is using eval-after-load, but it would be rather painful to put every tiny bit of my customization into an eval-after-load.

I'm afraid it might also be that I haven't grokked autoloads properly. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`autoload` is intended to be used to load functions from a certain file, not to load *additional* functionality - which is what it looks like you're trying to do.

Use [`eval-after-load`](http://www.gnu.org/s/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Hooks-for-Loading.html) instead:

```
(eval-after-load "erc" '(load "erc-mode-config"))
```

That tells Emacs to load the `erc-mode-config` library after the `"erc"` file has been loaded - which is what you want.  You could also use `'(require 'erc-mode-config)` if you have a `provide` statement inside of it.

The correct use of `autoload` is to load the actual file that contains the symbol.  So, by having

```
(autoload 'erc "erc-mode-config" "Load configuration for ERC" t)
```

You were telling Emacs to find the function `erc` by loading the `"erc-mode-config"` library, which isn't where the `erc` function is defined.  Also, the docstring is for the function in question, so the `autoload` statement above makes the help string for `erc` be `"Load configuration for ERC"` - which is also incorrect.

I'm guessing your first `autoload` example works because you have a `(require 'python)` statement in your config file... but that's just a guess.

Comment: Thank you, I had a nagging feeling that my autoloads were wrong :)

Comment: Also, you were right. My earlier configuration had (require 'python) followed by (require 'python-mode-config). I moved the (require 'python) command into the python-mode-config file when I rewrote it as a autoload. 

Now sitting and fixing all my autoloads and eval-after-loads.